# Select all records if parameter is -1

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, parameters

I know this is a basic question, but I can't seem to come up with the right combination of search terms to get the answer I need.

I'm working on a stored procedure where there is a parameter called `@AccountTypeId`. The parameter can be `1`, `2`, `3`, or `-1`. If `@AccountTypeId` is `-1` it should return **all** account types (`1`,`2`, and `3`). I can write a SP easily enough that will filter based on `@AccountTypeId`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Accounts_SP (@AccountTypeId INT)
AS
SELECT *
FROM Accounts
WHERE AccountTypeId = @AccountTypeId
```

The problem is having the SP return all `AccountType`s when `@AccountTypeId` is `-1`.

I've tried using a `CASE` statement in the `WHERE` clause like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Accounts_SP (@AccountTypeId INT)
AS
SELECT *
FROM Accounts
WHERE AccountTypeId IN (CASE @AccountTypeId WHEN -1
                            THEN (SELECT AccountTypeId FROM AccountTypes) 
                            ELSE @AccountTypeId 
                        END)
```

But it gives me the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I'm sure there is an easy way to get all the records and I'm just over-complicating things. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an OR statement, which of course is always true if you send in -1 and thus selects all rows.

```
SELECT *
FROM Accounts
WHERE AccountTypeId = @AccountTypeId
OR @AccountTypeId = -1
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple like this. I'll accept the answer after the time limit is up. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Every time I am faced with this requirement (and it is often), I make use of the [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function in SQL Server.  COALESCE returns the first non null value, so it would go something like this.  Note the @Param is changed to support NULL.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Accounts_SP (@AccountTypeId INT = NULL)
AS
SELECT *
FROM Accounts
WHERE AccountTypeId = COALESCE(@AccountTypeId, AccountTypeId)
```